# Unexpected token, expected "{"

Tags: typescript, jestjs, babel-jest

I am trying to set up jest to test my react code.
but i am running into the above error, at the < for state in below line

```
class app extends Component <State> {
```

this is my .babelrc file

```
{
"presets": [
    "@babel/preset-env",
    "@babel/preset-react"
]
}
```

need help desperately.
to be more clear this is my fake.spec.js. in the import statement i am facing a unexpected token import.

```
import React from 'react';

import app from '../src/app.react.js';

describe('App Snapshot', () => {
  test('renders', () => {
    const component = renderer.create(
      <app />
    );
    let tree = component.toJSON();
    expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
});
```

this is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
    "@material-ui/core": "^1.5.0",
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "chart.js": "^2.7.2",
    "jest": "^24.1.0",
    "js-cookie": "^2.2.0",
    "material-icons": "^0.2.3",
    "qrcode.react": "^0.9.2",
    "react": "^16.4.2",
    "react-chartjs-2": "^2.7.4",
    "react-dom": "^16.4.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
    "react-scripts": "^1.1.4",
    "universal-cookie": "^3.0.4",
    "unix-timestamp": "^0.2.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "jest",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.2.3",
    "@babel/core": "^7.3.4",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.3.4",
    "flow-bin": "^0.78.0"
  }
}
```

this is my file what i am trying to test app.react.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import 'themes/material/material.css';
import {graphql} from 'lib/graphql'


class app extends Component <State> {
  state = {
    app_config: {
      name: null,
      logo_image: null,
    };
...
```

Comment: Do add the error as well and perhaps more data on the class where things get stuck. Otherwise it hard to help. Also telling what things you tried will help.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks like TypeScript, so add `@babel/preset-typescript` to `presets` in `.babelrc`.
Oh, and you won't need `preset-env` then.

Comment: Do you have a `tsconfig.json`?

Comment: `{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "outDir": "./src/",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "module": "commonjs",
        "target": "es5",
        "jsx": "react"
    },
    "include": [
        "./src/**/*"
    ]
}` yea this is my tsconfig .

Comment: `import` is valid in TypeScript. Could you post the code where it gives that syntax error?